# delims varible doesnt match a string

Tags: batch-file, string-comparison, psexec

So our DNS somtimes goes a bit wrong and give out the wrong address.
So I created this code to make sure my script is working on the right computer.

However it always fails
It never matches at the IF?

extract:

```
SET /P Computer=Type here 
psexec \\%Computer% hostname >hostname.log
for /f "delims=" %%x in (hostname.log) do set hostname=%%x 
if not %hostname% == %computer% goto loopstart
```

Comment: what are the contents of `hostname` and `computer` ?

Comment: are you aware, you added a space to `%hostname%`? (`set hostname=%%x `); better use `set "hostname=%%x"`

Answer (score 0):

Always wrap your set variables in double quotes. As @Stephan mentioned in the above comment, you have a space after `set hostname=%%x` which will result in input + space which will not match input only as you are doing `==` meaning exact match.
Also, for doing possible matches where spaces might exist, add double quotes around variables for if statement as well, (although in this case PC names cannot contain spaces)

```
SET /P "Computer=Type here: " 
psexec \\%Computer% hostname >hostname.log
for /f "delims=" %%x in (hostname.log) do set "hostname=%%x" 
if not "%hostname%" == "%computer%" goto loopstart
```

You can test the result as well:

```
SET /P "Computer=Type here: " 
for /f "delims=" %%x in (hostname.log) do set "hostname=%%x" 
echo Hostname: "%hostname%" Computer: "%computer%"
```

Note that the above will match case sensitive objects only. So `PC1` will not match `Pc1` but `PC1` will match `PC1`

Comment: the space isn't really a problem with the OP's `if` (without quotes). The parser will handle the space. But it *is* a problem with the recommended quoted syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Computer` names can't contain spaces, you may be able to just use this:

```bat
Set /P "Computer=Type here "
For /F %%A In ('PsExec \\%Computer% HostName'
) Do If /I Not %%A==%Computer% (GoTo loopstart)
```

If your `Computer` can contain spaces, the following may work, *(untested doublequotes around `\\%Computer%`)*:

```bat
Set /P "Computer=Type here "
For /F "EOL=| Delims=" %%A In ('PsExec "\\%Computer%" HostName'
) Do If /I Not "%%A"=="%Computer%" (GoTo loopstart)
```

In either case, you can always change the `If` statement to an `If`/ `Else` should you need to use the output `%%A`. *(I've already enclosed the `GoTo` command in parentheses especially for that purpose, otherwise they can optionally be removed).*